# Different TileWallPaper on right and left side

Tags: graphics, multicol, backgrounds, article

I've A3 page layout, which is divided into two A4 paper layout. Currently there is same "TileWallPaper" used as background images on both A4 size layout of A3 paper. I'm looking for option to have different TileWallPaper on right & left side. Can you please suggest option for same? Same TeX file is mentioned below:

Note Currently `image opt3.jpg` is used in both columns; I want to use `opt3_right.jpg` & `opt3_left.jpg` on A3 paper with two two columns of A4 size.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a3paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in,headheight=3.5\baselineskip,headsep=1\baselineskip,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{datapie}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\TileWallPaper{0.5\paperwidth}{1\paperheight}{opt3}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{names}{namelist-7.csv}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Test Document
Test Document
Text Again
Text Again 22
\pagebreak
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your [example minimal](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) next time.

Comment: Sure, Next time i'll keep this in mind. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a fan of `background` package <sub>(and its author too `:-)`)</sub> :

```
\documentclass[landscape,a3paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in,headheight=3.5\baselineskip,headsep=1\baselineskip,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum} %% gives dummy text for this file
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
contents={
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at ($(current page.south west) + (.25\paperwidth,.5\paperheight)$) {\includegraphics[width=.5\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};
    \node at ($(current page.south east) + (-.25\paperwidth,.5\paperheight)$) {\includegraphics[width=.5\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This takes at least 2-3 compilation runs to stabilize.

Comment: Thanks Harish for giving new direction. somehow i'm not getting image in the background after using above mentioned code. Image is coming at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @PawanMude You have to compile atleast 2-3 times.

Comment: Thanks a lot Harish, it's working after 3rd compilation. Actually I'm using background as border for page, it's coming faint after using background package. Is there any option to keep background brightness as it is?

Comment: @PawanMude Put `opacity=1,` after `angle=0,` to make the image darker. Adjust the value between 0-1.

Comment: Thank You for introducing me to this package. As i am reading more about this package, i'm also becoming fan of it.

Comment: @PawanMude You are welcome :)